# I want to Datagrip IDE table row time format view as SqlDbx format

Tags: mysql, sql, ide, datagrip

Datagrip IDE -

[Datagrip IDE - Date, Time Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdgWf.png)
SqlDbx : 
[SqlDb - Date Time Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuYJ3.png)